# Translation of "to break up" in context of human relations

Tags: перевод, словоупотребление

Which possibilities are there to say ***to break up*** in context of human relations?

Maybe there are alternatives to ***разводиться*** which have a slightly different emphasis. I'm just asking, because ***разводиться*** sounds a bit "active", but I might be mistaken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**"Разводиться-развестись"** is "to get divorced"

I would translate *"to break up"* as **"расходиться-разойтись"**:

Че́рез пять лет отноше́ний они́ разошли́сь.
After five years of relations they broke up.

There is a colloquial synonym of "расходиться-разойтись" which is **"разбегаться-разбежаться"**:

Ну что́, вы уже разбежа́лись и́ли ещё вме́сте?
So, have you already broken up or are you still together?

Comment: Is there a phrase which has the relationship as subject, like in *the relationship went to pieces*?

Comment: You may say, for instance, "отношения полностью разрушились".

Comment: You may use "отношения развалились", though it is a bit graphic :) I mean, not the most delicate metaphor, more of a harsh truth.

Answer (score 10):

I would consider **расстаться** a more commonly used translation in context of dating couples (as opposed to married people):

```
- Мы расстались.
```

Comment: I second this -- this is the word my Russian friend used to refer to his break-up (Мы давно расстались)

Answer (score 6):

When talking about couples breaking up, it's common to use verb *расстаться*:

> Я расстался со своей бывшей прошлым летом.
>   I broke up with my ex last summer.

Yet, the context is important here, as the same verb may be used to describe a short-term temporary separation:

> Мы вышли из дома вместе и расстались на автобусной остановке [*до вечера*].
>   We came out of the house together and parted ways at the bus stop [*until evening*].

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a more passive sounding phrase, you can just say **«перестали встречаться»**. Although it probably would not be as useful in cases where people actually got married and then broke up **«расстались»** would be an alternative (as is already pointed out in Hardex's answer).